# @OneToMany relation between customer and item in order table. org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, one-to-many

I am currently learning hibernate and try to understand the relations. I am working on example of library data base. I have 3 tables:

Customer
Book
Order

In Customer and Book are information like name of customer, title of book etc. I would like to have a relation which customer ordered which book in order table. So I wrote the class:

```
@Entity
public class Order
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private Date date;
    private String status;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Book> books;

    @OneToOne
    private Customer customer;

//Getters, setters, constructors, etc...
```

As you can see above i implemented the relations:
@OneToMany - because in one order I can have many books ordered.

@OneToOne - because in one order I can have only one customer who ordered the books.

Below you can see my test class:

```
 public class Test
    {
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            DBManager dbManager = new DBManager();
            List <Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
            books.addAll(Arrays.asList(
            new Book(1,"Hobbit","JRR",10.2),//isbn,title,autor name, price
            new Book(2,"Witcher","Andrzej",20.3),
            new Book(3,"LOTR1","JRR",19.99),
            new Book(4,"LOTR2","JRR",29.99)));

            dbManager.addEntities(books);

            List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
            customers.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                    new Customer("A","M","W"),//name, surname, city
                    new Customer("K", "S", "Z"),
                    new Customer("P","Z","Z")
            ));
            dbManager.addEntities(customers);
            dbManager.addEntity(new Order(Date.valueOf("2019-06-01"),"nowy",books.subList(1,2), customers.get(0)));
        }
    }
```

The DBManager is a simple Util class:

```
public class DBManager
{
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    public <T> void addEntity(T t)
    {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(t);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public <T> void addEntities(List<T> entities)
    {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        entities.forEach(session::save);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the Test I have following exception:

```
cze 01, 2019 2:46:32 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
        INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.2.Final}
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:33 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
        WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
        INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb]
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
        INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
        INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 100 (min=1)
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:34 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:35 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
        INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@5fa23c] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
        Hibernate: create table Order (id bigint not null auto_increment, date date, status varchar(255), customer_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
        WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table Order (id bigint not null auto_increment, date date, status varchar(255), customer_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
        org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table Order (id bigint not null auto_increment, date date, status varchar(255), customer_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
        at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
        at DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:9)
        at Test.main(Test.java:11)
        Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (id bigint not null auto_increment, date date, status varchar(255), custom' at line 1
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 15 more

        Hibernate: alter table Order add constraint FKjd3x2xgs94mmspkead2wpjhgs foreign key (customer_id) references Customer (id)
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
        WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table Order add constraint FKjd3x2xgs94mmspkead2wpjhgs foreign key (customer_id) references Customer (id)" via JDBC Statement
        org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table Order add constraint FKjd3x2xgs94mmspkead2wpjhgs foreign key (customer_id) references Customer (id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
        at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
        at DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:9)
        at Test.main(Test.java:11)
        Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order add constraint FKjd3x2xgs94mmspkead2wpjhgs foreign key (customer_id) refer' at line 1
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 14 more

        Hibernate: alter table Order_Book add constraint FKh6ubcn53wu832xkdyp4bq2g4h foreign key (books_id) references Book (id)
        Hibernate: alter table Order_Book add constraint FKleoto2431q8tq7ulptjuk9526 foreign key (Order_id) references Order (id)
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
        WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table Order_Book add constraint FKleoto2431q8tq7ulptjuk9526 foreign key (Order_id) references Order (id)" via JDBC Statement
        org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table Order_Book add constraint FKleoto2431q8tq7ulptjuk9526 foreign key (Order_id) references Order (id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
        at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
        at DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:9)
        at Test.main(Test.java:11)
        Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (id)' at line 1
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 14 more

        Hibernate: insert into Book (ISBN, autorName, name, price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Book (ISBN, autorName, name, price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Book (ISBN, autorName, name, price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Book (ISBN, autorName, name, price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Customer (city, lastName, name) values (?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Customer (city, lastName, name) values (?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Customer (city, lastName, name) values (?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Order (customer_id, date, status) values (?, ?, ?)
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
        WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
        cze 01, 2019 2:46:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
        ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (customer_id, date, status) values (16, '2019-06-01', 'nowy')' at line 1
        Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3079)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3673)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:705)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:700)
        at DBManager.addEntity(DBManager.java:97)
        at Test.main(Test.java:29)
        Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (customer_id, date, status) values (16, '2019-06-01', 'nowy')' at line 1
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
        ... 23 more
```

Anyone know whac can be reason?

Comment: order if a SQL keyword. Choose another name for your table.

Comment: Also, A customer can have more than one orders, so it should be a ManyToOne, not a OneToOne.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank a lot, I forgot about it.

Comment: @JBNizet What is more. Now I have 4 tables:
book
customer
tb_order
tb_order_book

I do not want 4th table, but I want to have relation between order and book in tb_order table. How can it be done?

Comment: By using a JoinColumn annotation on your OneToMany. The default for a OneToMany is to use a join table. The association can't possibly be stored in the tb_order. Since an order has many books, you need a join table, or an additional order_id column in the book table.